# Aptana: How to remove unneeded ruble Bundles?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

How can i remove not needed ruble Bundles - like "CofffeeScript", "EngineYard", "Rubby" and otherones?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Aptana
2. Go to Window -> Show View -> Other
3. Open Studio -> Bundles
4. Bundles view should appear. Select it.
5. Expand bundles in question
6. Write down the path to the ruble folder. Most likely it will look like:
   `/path/to/aptana/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/88/1/.cp/bundles`
7. Go into that bundles folder, and delete rubles you don't want.
8. Make bundles folder READONLY (chmod 555)   *<- without this step, Aptana brings bundles back*
9. Restart Aptana.